# How to override trait variable name in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have scala trait as follows

```
trait Id {
            @javax.persistence.Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @BeanProperty
            var id: Long = _
}
```

Now I have an entity (Person) that I want to extend the Id trait but change the id column name to personid.
How can I achieve this?
Person Snippet Below:

```
@NamedQuery(name=”findAll”,query=”select p from Person p”)
class Person extends Id {
    @BeanProperty
    @Column(name=”personid”)
    def personid = id
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can introduce a method `personid` which returns the value of `id`:

```
trait Person extends Id {
  def personid = id
}
```

Removing the `id` member in `Person` would violate the principle that subclasses instances must always be usable as if they were instance of the base class. That is, if `Person` extends `Id`, then you must be able to call all the methods of `id` on it, otherwise you would not be able to assign an object of type `Person` to a reference of type `Id`.

So, if you extend `Id`, the extended trait/class will always have `id`.

You can, however, restrict the visibility of `id` in the base trait `Id` by making `id` package-private:

```
private[package_name] var id: Long = _
```

Comment: Now the insert works but when I tried to load the Entity list I get an error:
Unknown column ‘person0_.id’ in ‘field list’.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the complete concise snippet that you are executing?

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is to simply override the column name used by JPA to then you should be able to use the `AttributeOverride` annotation.

It might look something like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
trait Id {
        @javax.persistence.Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @BeanProperty
        var id: Long = _
}

@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="personid"))
class Person extends Id
```

If you want to change the property name used to access `id` then you could do something like Alex is suggesting...

**Edit:** Forgot to let the `Person` entity extend the `Id` trait